# Prevent variable iteration in bash script for loop

Tags: bash, iteration

I have a bash script in which i define a certain path as such:

`MY_PATH=/to/my/path`

I also have a set of directories within MY_PATH and I store these directories in an array, as such:

```
DIRECTORIES="/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir3/"
```

What I want to do is iterate over all the $DIRECTORIES in $MY_PATH, so I tried this:

```
for dir in $MY_PATH$DIRECTORIES
do
    echo "Processing $dir"
end
```

However, this gives the following undesired output:

```
Processing /to/my/path/dir1/           #Correct!
Processing /dir2/                      #What I want: Processing /to/my/path/dir2/
Processing /dir3/                      #What I want: Processing /to/my/path/dir3/
```

Is there any way to prevent iteration over $MY_PATH while preserving iteration over $DIRECTORIES so that I can achieve the desired output (see above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for dir in $DIRECTORIES; do
  path="$MY_PATH/$dir"
  echo "Processing $path"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not an array, btw.  Using an array would look like this:

```
MY_PATH=/to/my/path
DIRECTORIES=(dir1 dir2 dir3)
for dir in "${DIRECTORIES[@]}"; do
  path="$MY_PATH/$dir"
  echo "Processing $path"
done
```

(and this is not an answer, but the above code wouldn't fit in a comment.:))

Answer (score 0):

In case there are spaces in folder names

```
MY_PATH="/to/my/path"
```

And you are using newlines to separate folders as before

```
DIRECTORIES="/dir1/
/dir2/
/dir3/"
```

A slightly safer loop would be

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for dir in $DIRECTORIES; do
  path="$MY_PATH/$dir"
  echo "Processing $path"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```